# how to set an img src variable with jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, variables

here my code which is not working properly. (it is working if on line 4 I write **$("img").attr("src", image_src_1);** )

I guess I have to "variablize" line 4.

```
<script>
  var image_src_1 = "image.jpg";
  var x = 1;
  var new_source_for_image = "image_src_" + x; // I WANT IT TO BE image_src_1
  $("img").attr("src", new_source_for_image);  // (line 4)
</script>

<body>
  <img src="">
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't var new_source_for_image = "image_src_" + x need a file extension adding?

Answer (score 2):

that is because `new_source_for_image` represents name of variable and not variable itself. You need to use `.eval()` for evaluating the value out of it:

```
 $("img").attr("src", eval(new_source_for_image));
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at eval http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp. But, be careful to make sure you trust the data you run through eval. User data can be executed.